# Fundamental class of cotangent bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles

While reading some notes about index formula I found the expression which involved $[T^*M]$-the fundamental class of cotangent bundle. As far as I remember in order to speak about fundamental class $[M]$ two conditions must be satisfied:
1. $M$ has to be orientable
2. $M$ has to be closed.
These two conditions guarantee that $H_n(M,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ and in this circumstances $[M]$ is defined. In the case of cotangent bundle I would therefore like to ask:

> Why $T^*M$ is always orientable (as a manifold) (even if $M$ is not)?

Also appareantly $T^*M$ is never compact (therefore not closed) so

> How do we understand the fundamental class of $T^*M$?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give a reference to the notes that mentioned $[T^*M]$, because there are any number of things that could mean without specifying. Because a natural home for the index theorem is in $K$-theory, I would put good odds on it meaning $[T^*M] \in K_0(M)$. $T^*M$ is always orientable because, given a chart on $M$, there is a canonical chart on $T^*M$: $(x_1, \dots, x_n, dx_1, \dots, dx_n)$. Then you check that the transition maps always have positive determinant (and/or that this a smoothly chosen basis for the tangent space).

Comment: I don't have access to these notes in the moment, but the expression $[T^*M]$ appeared in the cohomological formula (after translation to cohomology, using the Chern character) and it was paired with the cohomological expression involving Chern character and Todd genus. Therefore it seems that it had to be understood as a homology class.